# Can't seem to click on the search

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, xhtml, internet-explorer-7

I have this [site](http://staging.playgolfplanet.com/) and for some reason in IE7 I can't click in the search field on the top right. Every other browser is fine.  I have not been able to check other versions of IE but I presume they are failing as well. What is going on?

Comment: when ever  open this site , my browser hangs in crome..

Comment: i have only ie8 , and it works fine in ie8...might not be a z-index problem

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say for sure since I don't have access to IE7 at the moment, but you might want to look into setting the [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_z-index.asp) of the input or its container.

Also, when I looked at your HTML it looked like something was malformed because I saw the attribute "value" without a value.  Double check all the HTML is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your link is password protected, but in addition to checking CSS `z-index` issues, you may want to try using the `position: relative;` and `zoom: 1;` properties in an IE7-conditional stylesheet — a combination of the two tends to fix a good portion of IE7 issues.  If you don't have the [IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535), it's invaluable for resolving display and functional issues.